# how to pass the sql statement using class,methods,parameters in asp.net

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

how to pass the SQL statement using class,methods,parameters in asp.net c# for this statement.
First I want to create a method and add parameter to call values.

```
protected void Btnsubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String Orders = "INSERT INTO Orders VALUES('" + DDLCustomerID.SelectedValue + "','" + Convert.ToInt32(TxtNetPrice.Text) + "');" + " SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();";
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(Orders, Connection))
        {
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            Connection.Open();
            int intID = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());
            String Orderdetails1 = "INSERT INTO OrderDetails VALUES(" + intID + ",'" + DDLProduct1.SelectedItem + "','" + Convert.ToInt32(TxtPrice1.Text) + "','" + Convert.ToInt32(TxtQuantity1.Text) + "','" + Convert.ToInt32(TxtTotalPrice1.Text) + "')";
            SqlCommand Command1 = new SqlCommand(Orderdetails1, Connection);
            Command1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            Command1.ExecuteNonQuery();
            String Orderdetails2 = "INSERT INTO OrderDetails VALUES(" + intID + ",'" + DDLProduct2.SelectedItem + " ','" + Convert.ToInt32(TxtPrice2.Text) + "','" + Convert.ToInt32(TxtQuantity2.Text) + "','" + Convert.ToInt32(TxtTotalPrice2.Text) + "')";
            SqlCommand Command2 = new SqlCommand(Orderdetails2, Connection);
            Command2.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            Command2.ExecuteNonQuery();
            String Orderdetails3 = "INSERT INTO OrderDetails VALUES(" + intID + ",'" + DDLProduct3.SelectedItem + " ','" + Convert.ToInt32(TxtPrice3.Text) + "','" + Convert.ToInt32(TxtQuantity3.Text) + "','" + Convert.ToInt32(TxtTotalPrice3.Text) + "')";
            SqlCommand Command3 = new SqlCommand(Orderdetails3, Connection);
            Command3.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            Command3.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Response.Write("<script>alert('Successfully Inserted');</script>");
            Connection.Close();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Better you use stored procedures and perform insert operation with in a transaction. Inline queries are always risky and open to sql injection.

Comment: can you give me syntax for creating class, method in this Inline queries @sdeep

Comment: What syntax are you looking for ? You can start by looking at: http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/classes/introduction/

Answer (score 0):

As your question suggests you absolutely HAVE TO use parameterised queries, to avoid SQL injection. Your code as it stands is directly susceptible to this I think where you include `DDLProduct1.SelectedItem` in your query string. Apologies if you know this already - it is worth being explicit for other people who land on this question in the future :o)

To parameterize a query using `SqlCommand` you need to use the `SqlCommand.Parameters` property:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx

Alternative approaches would be to use a good ORM such as Entity Framework. This parameterizes queries for you so there is no danger of forgetting. There are lots of good tutorials on this on the web, if you Google it

If you need to continue using `SqlCommand`, this is how you do it (using the example of your Orders query - the others are similar):

```
string Orders = "INSERT INTO Orders VALUES(@customerID, @price); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();";
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(Orders, Connection);

command.Parameters.Add("@customerID", SqlDbType.Int);
command.Parameters["@customerID"].Value = DDLCustomerID.SelectedValue;

command.Parameters.Add("@price", SqlDbType.Int);
command.Parameters["@price"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(TxtNetPrice.Text);
```

Be aware though, you need some error handing around the conversion - what happens if `TxtNetPrice` cannot convert to an integer?